# Delpoy a web application in azure but need AD authentication in our LAN

Tags: azure, ldap

I want to host a web app in Azure. But that app need user to be authenticated by a AD/LDAP server which locate in our LAN.

How can I do that? Just open TCP/636 port to Azure? any standard operation procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would generally have 3 options:
1. Synchronize directories between on-prem and Azure, use ADFS to authenticate people.
2. Create a site-to-site VPN, force traffic through that tunnel to talk to on-prem AD.
3. Just use public internet to talk to your AD (well, it is a bit crazy, but it's an option).

Comment: I will try second option. By doing so, maybe I can upload the web app without changing anything. thanks.